# -eq unary operator expected

Tags: bash, shell

I have this code here.
But I get the error:

```
./concatconvert: line 9: [: -eq: unary operator expected
./concatconvert: line 18: [: -eq: unary operator expected
```

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

param=$#
if [ $# -le 2 ]
then
 echo "Usage: concatconvert [-u|-1] FILE ...
 Description: concatenates FILE(s) to standard output separating them with divider -----. Optional first argument -u or -l converts contents to uppercase or lowercase,$
fi
if [ $1 -eq "-u" ]
then
 while [ $param -ge 1 ]
 do
  ./concat | awk '{print toupper($0)}'
  param=$(( param-1 ))
  shift
done
fi
if [ $1 -eq "-l" ]
then
 while [ $param -ge 1 ]
 do
 ./concat | awk '{print tolower($0)}'
 param=$(( param-1 ))
 shift
done
fi
```

Why am I getting this error? I thought that -eq is a unary operator?

Comment: In the expression `if [ $1 -eq "-u" ]`, you are quoting exactly the wrong things.  You need to use double quotes to deal with variable interpolation and the like, so although you can safely write `if [ "$1" -eq -u ]`, it is generally considered better style to write `if [ "$1" -eq "-u" ]`

Comment: But `-eq` is used to compare integers, so comparing with `-u` is probably not what you want in any case.

Comment: `-eq` is a binary operator. It expects to be preceded by a parameter.  If `$1` is empty you will get an error.  Test with `echo $1` before the `if`

Answer (score 3):

You have missed few things eg--> `"` for `echo` command was NOT closed. Then in `if` condition since you are comparing a string so change it to `if [[ "$1" = "-u" ]]` so following could be the script(I haven't tested it since no samples were there).

```
#!/bin/bash

param=$#
if [ $# -le 2 ]
then
 echo "Usage: concatconvert [-u|-1] FILE ...
 Description: concatenates FILE(s) to standard output separating them with divider -----. Optional first argument -u or -l converts contents to uppercase or lowercase,$"
fi
if [[ "$1" = "-u" ]]
then
 while [ $param -ge 1 ]
 do
  ./concat | awk '{print toupper($0)}'
  param=$(( param-1 ))
  shift
done
fi
if [[ $1 -eq -l ]]
then
 while [ $param -ge 1 ]
 do
 ./concat | awk '{print tolower($0)}'
 param=$(( param-1 ))
 shift
done
fi
```

Comment: @user20304030, Could you please check this solution and let me know if this helped you?